# How to get the association name in rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, callback, associations

I have the following association code in my user.rb model file

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_messages, class_name: 'ChatMessage', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
  has_many :received_messages, class_name: 'ChatMessage', foreign_key: 'receiver_id'
end
```

I want a method in the ChatMessage model which should be triggered by the following

```
current_user.sent_messages
current_user.received_messages
```

The method should return the name of the association that was called. 
Eg:

```
class ChatMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_find :get_association_name
  def get_association_name
    self.association_name // this should return sent_message or received_message depending on whether current_user.sent_messages or current_user.received_messages was called
  end
end
```

Is there a way to get this association name in rails?
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us in which class you are having haS_many associations, Please complete that code.

Comment: Have updated the code..please check

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, exactly what you are looking for, but

```
CurrentUser.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)
```

will give an array of all has_many associations.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response..can you please check the question again, I've updated it

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used AR associations extensions for cases like this, but you should be able to do:

```
has_many :sent_messages, class_name: 'ChatMessage', foreign_key: 'sender_id' do
  def get_association_name; 'sent_messages'; end
  # or, to make this more generic,
  # def get_association_name; proxy_association.reflection.name.to_s; end
end
```

And the method should be accessible from your relation. If you were using Rails 4, you could extract the generic version out into a separate module to extend your associations more succinctly. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions.

**EDIT**

Try:

```
has_many :sent_messages, class_name: 'ChatMessage', foreign_key: 'sender_id' do
  def and_set_type
    proxy_association.target.each do |msg|
      msg.update_attribute(:type, 'sent')
    end
    scoped
  end
end
```

And then access your `sent_messages` with `current_user.sent_messages.and_set_type`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response..can you please check the question again, I've updated it

Comment: I think you should be able to define an association extension with your simple message; see updated answer.

Comment: I just tested it and updated my answer with an option to just get the string value of the association name.

Comment: Actually I have an attr_accessor :type in my chat_message model which I want to set to 'sent' or 'received' when the objects are retrived using current_user.sent_messages or current_user.received_messages